# How to redirect in JAX-RS after a post to a get

Tags: rest, redirect, jax-rs

I'm developing a simple login form (security is not a problem) where the user visits the page `login` inserts *username* and *password* and press *send* that POST these information to the page `check`.

Page `check` checks credential and, if everything is OK, creates cookie and redirect to page `home`, otherwise redirects to page `login`.

I use the following redirect:

```
return Response.temporaryRedirect(new URI("/home")).cookie(cookie, cookie2).build();
```

This redirects from `check` (@POST method) to `home` (@POST method), I just wanna to redirect to `home` (@GET method).

**Important note**: I'm a newbie of JAX and what I would like to create is a RESTful service. Are redirects a correct way to implement a REST service?

Now I'll show you small slices of code hoping:

`check` Page

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response checkLogin(@FormParam(Login.fieldUsername) String user, @FormParam(Login.fieldPsw) String psw) throws URISyntaxException {
    boolean val = db.checkLogin(user, psw);
    NewCookie cookie;
    NewCookie cookie2;
    if(val){
        //Valid access + cookie creation
        cookie = new NewCookie("username", user);
        cookie2 = new NewCookie("hashedPassword", psw);
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(new URI("/home")).cookie(cookie, cookie2).build();
    } else {
        //Wrong login + cookie deletion
        cookie = new NewCookie("username", "");
        cookie2 = new NewCookie("hashedPassword", "");
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(new URI("/login")).cookie(cookie, cookie2).build();
    }
}
```

`login` page

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response showLoginForm() throws URISyntaxException{
    boolean validCookie = db.checkLogin(username, hashedPassword);

    String data = "<form name='Username' action='"+ redirect +"' method='post'><ul>"
            + "<li><label for='"+fieldUsername+"'>Username</label>"
            +   "   <input type='text' name='"+fieldUsername+"' placeholder='Insert username' required></li>"
            + "<li><label for='"+fieldPsw+"'>Password</label>"
            +   "   <input type='password' name='"+fieldPsw+"' placeholder='Insert password' required></li>"
            + "<li><input type='submit' value='Login'>"
            + "</li></ul></form>";
    if(validCookie){
        return Response.temporaryRedirect(new URI(homepage)).build();
    }
    else {
        return Response.ok( showTheForm(data) ).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: No they are not, REST should not dictate the flow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Response.seeOther(redirecttUri).build();
```